# Trouble with friendly URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having trouble generating a friendly url using htaccess.  I would like something like this,

Origin:  /temp/info.php?j=1&m=2
Destination: /temp/info/1/2/

Based on some other answers on here I used the following htaccess rules,

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /temp/info\.php\?j=([^&]+)&m=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ temp/info/%2/%3/? [R=301,L]
```

This sends me to the correct URL (/temp/info/1/2/), however I get Undefined index j and m errors.  So I added the next bit but it seems to be to none effect,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?temp/info/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /temp/info.php?j=$1&m=$2 [L]
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?  The second rule seems to be getting ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /info\.php\?j=([^&]+)&m=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /~temp/info/%1/%2/? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?:^|/)info/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /~temp/info.php?j=$1&m=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will server `/file.php`.

Comment: Hi, with this added now throws a 404 error.  I should add I am doing this on a local machine with Options +FollowSymLinks and RewriteEngine On as my only other htaccess rules.

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess file and are there other rules also in this `.htaccess`?

Comment: Only other rule is RewriteBase /,  I am running OS X and the test site is located in /Users/temp/Sites directory, that is also where the .htaccess is located

Comment: Is `temp` s sub directory under `/Users/temp/Sites/`

Comment: No but to visit the site I go to 127.0.0.1/~temp/info.php?j=1&m=2.  First rule redirects to 127.0.0.1/~temp/info/1/2/

Comment: By the way I left out the tilde in the question, although I am using it in the htaccess

Comment: 127.0.0.1/~temp/info.php?j=1&m=2 redirecting to 127.0.0.1/info/1/2/, but 404 error.  Is this working on your end?  Perhaps it is the way my local machine is set up?  I wonder if I would have better success on my actual website.

Comment: now being redirect to http://127.0.0.1/Users/temp/Sites/info/1/2/ but still 404 error.  I tried in chrome, firefox, safari, clear cache, all same result.